# Any way to determine if HTML5 viewport is occluded by other windows in popular browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, ecmascript-6

I doubt there would be a general Javascript method for doing this, but is there perhaps any way to determine if the viewport or window.document (the renderable portion of the window) is occluded by other windows prior to the window.document regaining focus?

The reason I want this functionality is that I would like to, upon regaining focus, avoid the typical input processing of the first left mouse click on the window if and only if the window was at least partially occluded. A person who has full visibility of the window intuitively expects that first click to cause interaction, regardless of focus status, however, if the window is obstructed, that first click is typically made with the intent bringing the window to the forefront without interaction.

All searches are yielding are methods to determine if an element is visible in your viewport, which is completely different.

Edit: I noticed that finance.yahoo.com has videos that are automatically muted when they are not visible. I'm not sure how that is accomplished, but perhaps the same mechanism could be used if someone knows what it is.

Comment: I'm mainly on macOS these days and have hardly seen how other OS desktop envs do behave, but I'd assume this behavior to be managed by the OS directly. At least on my mac, when I first click on a window of a "below" application, said application doesn't receive the click event, it only gains focus. So you as a web author wouldn't even know if the window gained focus through a click event or by other means (like keyboard app-switch, or the unexpected killing of the previous "front" app).

Comment: Note that for the question itself, there is [this](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/6211) which tries to define an "has user-attention" new kind of focus, but that would be mainly for spec authors to use, and I doubt it would be accessible to web authors (i.e JS), though there may be ways of deriving this info and thus maybe someday it might be part of a public API. But the fact that today specs don't even have a way of knowing that, means that today there isn't any API exposing that info either.